# Difference between DAG import in two ways?

Tags: airflow

I am trying to create dynamic dag but seems to be failing at the minute. I came across creating the DAG object in two different:

- `from airflow.models import DAG` https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#latest-run-only
- `from airflow import DAG` https://airflow.apache.org/tutorial.html
  This really confused me because within the same documentation there are two ways of instantiating DAG object.

Answer (score 5):

Both are importing the same DAG class.  Just an attribute of how python imports works.

When you do `from airflow.models import DAG` python is importing the models file and assigning the variable DAG to the DAG class defined in the models file.

When you do `from airflow import DAG` python is importing the variable DAG defined in [**init**.py](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/__init__.py), which is in fact just `from airflow.models import DAG`.

A minimal version being:

### models.py

```
class DAG():
    pass
```

### **init**.py

```
from airflow.models import DAG
```

### dags/dag_file.py

```
# import __init__.py which imports models.py which contains DAG
from airflow import DAG

# or this which just imports models.py which contains DAG
from airflow.models import DAG
```

All that being said, if your dynamic DAG is failing, I doubt it's related to this import

Comment: I am using the 'from airflow import DAG' in my composer DAG and I do not have any __init__.py file in my dags folder but it still works fine. I see airflow core package's [init.py file has imported the models.dag](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/34e1f3167c7a7d4a3d6cf909973981c86c034e5c/airflow/__init__.py#L125) and may be when I just import airflow as a package, DAG object is imported too. My question is __init__.py file was not needed here but why so? Any explanation or suggestions would help me understand this. Thanks.